# Seeking concise expression or word for "Taking ownership of an existing term used by an adversary, then using it against them."

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, concision

As example:
"“While we have already tried to build a new and viable society around concepts such as democracy, sustainability, sustainable development and resilience, **all these terms have been corrupted by forces determined to incorporate and embed them into the** Anthropocene where they become ‘business as usual’.” in  [Exiting The Anthropocene and Entering The Symbiocene.](https://glennaalbrecht.com/2015/12/17/exiting-the-anthropocene-and-entering-the-symbiocene/)

I seek a word or shorter phrase to express the words in bold font.

Also encountered in a French language conversation when the term - neo-colonialism - was taken and used in a manner contrary to it's original intention.

A word or short expression for using the enemy's (verbal) weapons against them.

Comment: I'd probably use 'debasing the terms', but 'debase' is hypernymic.

Comment: Sounds like [hijacking](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hijack) = stealing and redirecting something for your own purposes.

Comment: Another related term is 'pejoration', the downgrading of a word's meaning (towards a more pejorative sense); 'silly' originally meant 'happy', 'blissful'. 'Knave' was once synonymous with 'boy', but now means 'rogue' or worse. But this is usually a  semantic shift over a lengthy period.